# How do I change my foreach loop to a for loop?

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, foreach

so I would like to change my foreach loop to a for loop but the one I did does not work correctly.

So, the code I want to convert to a for loop is

```
    Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(process);        
    if (p.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (ProcessModule m in p[0].Modules)
                {

                }
```

but the one that I made is

```
     Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(process);      
    if (procez.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < procez[0]; i++)
                {

                }
```

It shows an error that I can not use the "<" operator to argument operations

Comment: The middle part is wrong, you need `for (int i = 0; i < procez.Length; i++)`. However, why change it? Also, the 2 blocks of code are seemingly completely unrelated, please be more careful with your posts.

Comment: Second code you refer to `procez` variable. Please include where it's created into the sample.

Answer (score 1):

try like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < p[0].Modules.Length; i++)
{
  ....
}
```